# How to identify an Image as a screenshot

Tags: python, image, image-processing, computer-vision, screenshot

I am trying to detect if an image is a screenshot or an image captured by phone. Currently, I am using 'pyexifinfo' library to get the image headers and analyzing them to get the info like image source and other info. But i am not able to identify a lot of images as screenshots.

Is there any standard method or a hack to identify a screenshot?

Comment: Short answer: No, there is no standard method

Comment: @miindlek Is there any hack we can use other than using image headers

Comment: No, not even by using image headers.

Comment: Very broad. What is a screenshot for you? What is an image captured by phone? If a screenshot is something like *store all display pixels to some image*, it will have no noise (at least in some parts of the image; ignoring a full-screen screenshot of showing a image taken by some camera; noise introduced by lossy-compression is different). An image captured / shot by your phone will have a lot of noise. This could be exploited besides more complex stuff like looking for templates like icons or very parallel axes and so on.Minimal test:Resize both classes to same dims: zip/png it, compare bytes